# How to deploy a secured web application to weblogic managed server

Tags: java, security, weblogic, oracle-adf

We have an ADF web application with ADF security mechanism. It works properly if deployed on Admin Server, Spaces. But when I deploy it on a managed server just created by me, login.jspx doesn't appear, neither exception and something else. I tried to determine what libraries might be different, but I can not spot anything.

What might be the reason?

Comment: I don't think there are enough details in your question for anyone to help you. Your managed server logs don't say anything? Have you redeployed? Does the web app work when you disable the security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you forget to apply JRF template to your server/domain.

Check this tutorial for details: [ADF Deployment Guide](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jdeveloper/howto/11114/managedserver/wlsadfms.html)

Comment: yes you're right, and additionally i added "adf.oracle.domain, adf.oracle.domain.webapp" libraryrefs into weblogic-application.xml

Comment: And i should underline one point, that link is usefull for me: http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2009/09/hint-for-oracle-adf-application.html